# How do MyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation() and getLastFix() differ?

Tags: android, mylocationoverlay

Looking at MyLocationOverlay - does anyone know what the difference is between:

```
public GeoPoint getMyLocation();
public android.location.Location getLastFix();
```

[MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html)

(besides the return type)? Does the getMyLocation() method return a value only after a location has been found, and the getLastFix() will return a cached last fix, possibly from a different session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs both relate to `most-recently-set user location`, so I'd say that both returns last cached location, and `getMyLocation` just provides type conversion from `Location` to `GeoPoint`.